# Не находит путь к файлам стилей

Tags: node.js, express

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Пытаюсь подключить файл стилей таким образом, но всегда получаю 404 ошибку, почему он не может найти путь к этому файлу? (Подключение идёт с файла index.html в главной директории `public`)

Сама структура файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На серверной части так же прописал путь к статикам:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"/css/style.css" читается как абсолютный путь от корня. Относительй путь — с точкой в начале, обозначающей текущий каталог: "./css/style.css".